# How to get the text from Textbox in another app? Window Inspector / Spy++

Tags: c#, textbox, window, inspector, spy++

I have used Window Inspector and Spy++ to try and find a specific Textbox in a 3rd party app.
It seems I found the box, as the Rect coordinates match what I expected.

But how do I get the text from this Textbox?
I can possibly filter through all the details that Spy++ and Window Inspector give me, but I can't seem to find a way of getting the entire "pool of information" Window Inspector and Spy++ give me.

The Window at Textbox details below:

> **Window**
>
> Children: 0x000601f4 • Class: "#32770" • Rect: X=539, Y=513, W=450,
> H=358 • Style: 0x40000044 • StyleEx: 0x00000000 • Min: False • Max:
> False • PID: 5124 • Path: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\My App\My App.exe'

`

> **Textbox**
>
> 0x00010660 • Class: "Edit" • Rect: X=550, Y=599, W=429, H=224 • Style:
> 0x503100c4 • StyleEx: 0x00000204 • Min: False • Max: False • PID: 5124
> • Path: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\My App\My App.exe'

Comment: I would suggest checking the accessibility APIs, they are designed for things like screen readers and should allow traversal of all text in a window, but It is not something I have done myself. And I'm not sure if c# wrappers are available, you might need to do win32 calls.

Comment: Use UI Automation API instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview you can try before any coding with inspect.exe tool from Windows SDK or the newer Accessibility Insights: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects if they can see the text you can get it with the API

Answer (score 2):

Hope I'm not misunderstanding the question. It should be simple enough

For `Windows Inspector` the textbox contents should be under `Text (normal)`:

[image: Windows Inspector]

For `Spy++` the textbox contents should be under `Caption`

[image]

Comment: Good sense of direction, but what I'm trying to find is the IntPtr handle of the TextBox. It seems the handle is a "child-of-a-child-of-a-child..." essentially deeper into the "treeview" of handles and I can only get a list of top level (parent) branches of handles.

Comment: sorry, maybe I'm still not getting it, but the Windows Handle/Handle in the pictures is the IntPtr of the textbox, not its parent form.

Comment: You are correct, it is the handle of the textbox, but how do I find this handle on C#? I can hard-code it, but next time I restart the app owning the textbox, it will be a different handle.

Comment: I can get the text if I hard-code the IntPtr, but this pointer will change each time I open the app, so I need to find a way of going through each IntPtr. Can I do a system-wide search of all IntPtrs and check their Rect property?

Comment: I see what you are asking now, I'm not sure how to do it but I'm sure its possible but perhaps you should clarify the question as when I read it its not clear that you asking for a programmatic approach outside of the spy++/inspector.